# React Router infinite loop in onAbort

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm writing a very simple app to learn `react-router`. 
When a client wants to visit a page (`products`, `about`, `home`) and it's not logged in , it is redirected to the login page , and after logging in , it is redirected back to the same page it wanted to visit.

This is the definition of the router :

```
var router = function(req, res, next) {
    var router = Router.create({
        routes: routes,
        onAbort: function(abortReason) {
            var url = router.makePath(abortReason.to, abortReason.params, abortReason.query);
            res.redirect(url);
        }
    });
    router.run(function(Handler, state) {
        var initialState = {};
        var markup = React.renderToString(<Handler {...initialState}/>);
        res.render('react-app', {
            markup: markup,
            state: JSON.stringify(initialState)
        });
    });
};
```

routes :

```
var routes = (
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
        <Route path="about" name="about" handler={About} />
        <Route path="products" name="products" handler={Products} />
        <Route path="login" name="login" handler={Login} />
        <DefaultRoute name="home" handler={Home} />
    </Route>
);
```

About.js (a page which user must be logged in to be able to visit):

```
'use strict';

    var React = require('react');
var loginStore = require('../stores/LoginStore');
var About = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'About',
    statics: {
        willTransitionTo(transition) {
            if (!loginStore.isLoggedIn()) {
                loginStore.setTransitionPath(transition.path);
                transition.redirect('login');
            }
        }
    },
    _getLoginState() {
        return {
            userLoggedIn: loginStore.isLoggedIn()
        };
    },
    componentDidMount() {
        this.changeListener = this._onChange;
        loginStore.addChangeListener(this.changeListener);
    },
    _onChange() {
        this.setState(this._getLoginState());
    },
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            userLoggedIn: this._getLoginState()
        };
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        loginStore.removeChangeListener(this.changeListener);
    },
    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
            message: 'Default Prop for About page'
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        return (<div>
        {this.props.message}
        </div>);
    }
});

module.exports = About;
```

Login.js (The login page):

```
'use strict';

    var React = require('react');
    var AuthenticationServices = require('../Services/AuthenticationService');
    var Login = React.createClass({

        displayName: 'Login',

        propTypes: {},

        getDefaultProps: function() {
            return {
                message: 'Default Prop for Login page'
            };
        },
        _login: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            AuthenticationServices.login('arian', '1111');
        },
        _logout: function() {
            e.preventDefault();
            AuthenticationServices.logout();
        },
        render: function() {
            return (<div>
                <button type="button" onClick={this._login}>Log in</button>
                <button type="button" onClick={this._logout}>Log out</button>
            </div>);
        }
    });

    module.exports = Login;
```

From what I understood, when `redirect` is called (either on `transition` or `response`) `onAbort` is called on server-side and this causes an infinite loop to happen which crashes on server-side. Because there's another redirect in `onAbort` function which makes `onAbort` being called again and again.

How do I have to solve this issue ? Is there anything in `onAbort` that I'm missing ?

Bitbucket repository for the code (although it doesn't work because I copied it from somewhere else , so the environment is not set ) :
https://bitbucket.org/arianhosseinzadeh/react-router-poc

**UPDATE**

It turned out that the source of the problem is in the definition of routes :

var routes = (
    
        
        
        
        
    
);

So as you can see in About.js, if the client is not logged in , it will be redirected to login. (Same happens with other components including home)

home is the DefaultRoot, so when the client wants to browse / (without being logged in) it will be routed to home component. And it will be redirected to login WHICH surprisingly will AGAIN renders home and it falls into a infinite loop.

Please refer to this question if you are curious why this happens :

willTransitionTo of DefaultRoute comes into action even though it's not supposed to

Comment: I'm not sure it's clear what your question is.

Comment: @Clarkie : I edited the question trying to make it more clear. Well, the problem is the infinite loop of the `onAbort` function.

Comment: Can you post the code above the `router.run` that is actually handling the `req` / `res`?

Comment: @BradBumbalough : edited and added

Comment: Are you using express or?..

Comment: @BradBumbalough : I just added the bitbucket repo to the post , it doesn't work as I copied the code form another repo , but one can at least take a look at the code